# process in gravity forms to get data by list id

Tags: php, wordpress

in the gravity form plugin how to get all the data of  the entries by a particular list id.

```
$lead_id = $_REQUEST['detailsid'];
$lead = RGFormsModel::get_lead( $lead_id ); 
$form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( $lead['form_id'] );
```

Comment: Are you looking to get all entries by form ID?

Comment: yes right sir how we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access all entries of a given form like so:

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, array(), null, array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 99999 ) );
```

It doesn't look like there is a way to guarantee that you're getting all entries without setting the page size to a ridiculous number. I'll look into that.

More information on the GFAPI::get_entries() method here: http://inlinedocs.gravityhelp.com/class-GFAPI.html#_get_entries